# Spawning node.js server with nginx

Tags: nginx, wintersmith

So this is something new to me. I have a node.js Application running on my server on Port 3000. I have an nginx Proxy:

```
upstream websli_nodejs_app_2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

# this is the dynamic websli server
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.ch;
#root /var/www/websli/public;


# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://websli_nodejs_app_2/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

This works like a charm. Now I'm spawning (at least I believe that's what it's called). More node application. That's where Wintersmith comes in place: I'm running wintersmith preview

On my localhost that will result in another node.js server on localhost:8000. When I then go to localhost:8000 in my browser I'm getting the expected result, but then on my localhost I don't have the nginx proxy setup.

**The issue:**

Now on my production setup with nginx, I'm a bit stuck because I obviously cannot access localhost:8000

I have tried to add another upstream server, but this didn't really worked out. I have then also tried to spawn on something like dev.test.ch:8000, but that would result in something like error listen EADDRNOTAVAIL

**What I'm looking for**

The goal is to start another server from inside my main node.js server and make it accessible from a browser. Any input is highly welcomed.

Comment: With wintersmith you would build the website and upload them to the server to be served as static files, no need to run nodejs up there. Or is there something I did not understand?

Comment: Yes, I'm building the site on the server

Comment: A little late, but why not build on server but still serve as static files? Configure `config.json` so it outputs to a build folder that nginx can serve

Comment: Well, but I would want to use the preview server, so that changes are not automatically being deployed to production. ... Project is old though. Thanks for your comment anyways.